# How to get column of a table (say, x) using its 'x_id' column which references the 'id' of another table in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, schema

I have a table: stage_types, with the following columns: 'id', 'name', 'created_at'

Another table: stages, with the following: 'id', 'x_id', 'name', 'created_at'

Say I have this:

STAGES

**'id'    'stage_type_id'     'name'     'created_at'**

1              1(the id)               name1          2020/00/00

2              1(the id)                name2      2020/00/00

3              2(the id)                name3            2020/00/00

STAGE_TYPES

**'id'       'name'     'created_at'**

1        something      2020/00/00

2        something      2020/00/00

3        something      2020/00/00

Inside the stages table, the column 'stage_type_id' is created using:

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('stage_type_id');
        $table->foreign('stage_type_id')->references('id')->on('stage_types');
```

How can I, in the controller, **START WITH STAGES TABLE** i.e. DB::table('stages')..... and refer to the **name** of the stage type using the 'stage_type_id' column?

Model relationships:

- A stage belongsTo a StageType
- StageType hasOne stage

(this could be the wrong way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear on what you are trying to achieve and why would you go with the `DB` facade.

If, as you said:

> A stage belongsTo a StageType

Then you would refer to the stage type using the name of the function defining the relationship:

Say you have, in the Stages Model:

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StageType::class);
}
```

You would refer to the Stages Type something like:

```
$stage = App\Stage::first();
$nameOfStageType = $stage->types->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This join for two tables.
In SQL( 'SELECT * FROM stages JOIN stage_type on stages.id = stage_type.stage_id ' )**

$joinedTables = App\Stage::join('stage_type','stages.id','=','stage_type.stage_id')->get();

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26195010)